# how to create a date variable from a long string

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

[image]

samples data can be build using codes:

```
df<-structure(list(LSAF..Date.acted.On. = structure(c(33L, 18L, 7L, 
32L, 51L, 47L, 2L, 45L, 38L, 15L), .Label = c("Aug 13, 2019, 10:44:07 AM GMT-04:00", 
"Aug 13, 2019, 10:45:47 AM GMT-04:00", "Aug 13, 2019, 10:47:20 AM GMT-04:00", 
"Aug 13, 2019, 10:53:29 AM GMT-04:00", "Aug 13, 2019, 10:54:54 AM GMT-04:00", 
"Aug 13, 2019, 10:57:11 AM GMT-04:00", "Aug 13, 2019, 10:58:13 AM GMT-04:00", 
"Feb 13, 2020, 1:13:07 PM GMT-05:00", "Feb 13, 2020, 1:17:07 PM GMT-05:00", 
"Feb 22, 2019, 11:13:51 AM GMT-05:00", "Jan 28, 2020, 11:19:19 AM GMT-05:00", 
"Jan 28, 2020, 11:21:28 AM GMT-05:00", "Jan 7, 2020, 9:59:28 AM GMT-05:00", 
"Jul 13, 2020, 9:17:01 PM GMT-04:00", "Jul 15, 2020, 9:08:54 PM GMT-04:00", 
"Jul 18, 2019, 11:15:26 AM GMT-04:00", "Jul 23, 2020, 10:50:32 AM GMT-04:00", 
"Mar 5, 2020, 10:00:07 AM GMT-05:00", "Mar 5, 2020, 10:01:22 AM GMT-05:00", 
"Mar 5, 2020, 9:56:36 AM GMT-05:00", "Mar 5, 2020, 9:58:31 AM GMT-05:00", 
"Mar 6, 2020, 1:17:17 PM GMT-05:00", "May 13, 2019, 11:07:52 AM GMT-04:00", 
"May 14, 2019, 2:32:40 PM GMT-04:00", "May 16, 2019, 3:46:08 PM GMT-04:00", 
"May 16, 2019, 4:23:27 PM GMT-04:00", "May 16, 2019, 4:25:40 PM GMT-04:00", 
"May 16, 2019, 4:29:12 PM GMT-04:00", "May 16, 2019, 4:40:58 PM GMT-04:00", 
"May 21, 2019, 2:22:07 PM GMT-04:00", "Nov 13, 2020, 4:14:55 PM GMT-05:00", 
"Nov 13, 2020, 4:21:06 PM GMT-05:00", "Nov 13, 2020, 4:24:07 PM GMT-05:00", 
"Nov 13, 2020, 9:10:19 AM GMT-05:00", "Nov 24, 2020, 10:51:52 AM GMT-05:00", 
"Oct 15, 2020, 3:46:52 PM GMT-04:00", "Oct 15, 2020, 3:48:35 PM GMT-04:00", 
"Oct 17, 2019, 9:09:20 PM GMT-04:00", "Oct 18, 2019, 11:15:51 AM GMT-04:00", 
"Oct 20, 2020, 1:28:57 PM GMT-04:00", "Oct 26, 2020, 1:52:26 PM GMT-04:00", 
"Oct 26, 2020, 2:15:11 PM GMT-04:00", "Oct 29, 2019, 1:55:53 PM GMT-04:00", 
"Oct 9, 2019, 10:39:10 AM GMT-04:00", "Oct 9, 2019, 10:45:14 AM GMT-04:00", 
"Sep 11, 2020, 2:40:34 PM GMT-04:00", "Sep 19, 2019, 2:45:46 PM GMT-04:00", 
"Sep 23, 2019, 2:24:01 PM GMT-04:00", "Sep 9, 2019, 10:16:01 AM GMT-04:00", 
"Sep 9, 2019, 10:22:23 AM GMT-04:00", "Sep 9, 2019, 10:25:03 AM GMT-04:00", 
"Sep 9, 2019, 10:32:44 AM GMT-04:00"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

How can I modify the data so it can be used as a date variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```r
as.Date(df$LSAF..Date.acted.On.,
        format = "%b %d, %Y, %I:%M:%S %p")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lubridate`'s `mdy_hms`

```
df$date_time <- lubridate::mdy_hms(df$LSAF..Date.acted.On.)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date_time)
head(df)

#.                LSAF..Date.acted.On.           date_time       date
#1  Nov 13, 2020, 4:24:07 PM GMT-05:00 2020-11-13 21:24:07 2020-11-13
#2  Mar 5, 2020, 10:00:07 AM GMT-05:00 2020-03-05 15:00:07 2020-03-05
#3 Aug 13, 2019, 10:58:13 AM GMT-04:00 2019-08-13 14:58:13 2019-08-13
#4  Nov 13, 2020, 4:21:06 PM GMT-05:00 2020-11-13 21:21:06 2020-11-13
#5  Sep 9, 2019, 10:25:03 AM GMT-04:00 2019-09-09 14:25:03 2019-09-09
#6  Sep 19, 2019, 2:45:46 PM GMT-04:00 2019-09-19 18:45:46 2019-09-19
```